# Fastest algorithm that determines whether a given DFA is minimal?

Tags: algorithms, finite-automata

NOTE - I can't find a good answer in the Similar question above ^

Given a DFA, is there a fast algorithm that determines whether it's minimal?

I'm looking for an algorithm that works faster than just minimizing the DFA and checking if the number of states changed. i.e, faster than Hopcroft's O(n*s*log(n)).

I already find the question [here](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/22191/how-fast-can-we-decide-whether-a-given-dfa-is-minimal), but there was not any solution there.. No algorithm was presented as a solution.

Comment: Your _question_ seems to be the same one as the one marked as duplicate. If you think there is an important difference, please explain so. It seems that the reason there is no algorithm described as answer to the other question, is that a better algorithm that Hopcroft's is not known.

Comment: The other question makes it clear that nothing better is known. What are you hoping for? It seems unlikely that a Stack Exchange answer is going to advance the state of the art in such a fundamental problem.

Comment: I am not sure why is it clear from the other question that no better algorithm is known. It looks like there isn't any algorithm with better space-complexity, but that's not what I'm looking for.  In fact there was suggested an algorithm in the comments, but I'm not sure if it can be used for this problem efficiently.